# How can I transfer ownership of a business page from my Facebook account to another?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-business-manager

I was a volunteer with a non-profit society and I have their Facebook page linked to my account, as I was the person keeping it updated.  They now have a full time staff that would like to keep the page current and I find myself playing less of a role on the page.  Can I transfer the page to another person, or is it forever linked to my page?  I fear if I delete it, they will lose all of the content and a lot of hard work.  I have already added people as administrators, but I would prefer to not be involved anymore.  Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to transfer your Facebook PAGE to another person or account (who must have a Facebook profile) you need to ensure that they are your Facebook "Friend" or have "Liked" your PAGE.

Go to your PAGE to manage the Admins > click "Edit Page" > Admin Roles. And start typing name so it appears and click on the profile to place it in the box, and then click "Save Changes".

If the name method doesn't work, try entering their email address in the box as that often works.

And if that doesn't work try below, as sometimes there is a glitch doing it the "correct" way.

Click > Edit Page . . . and RIGHT-CLICK on "See Banned Users" and "Open in New Tab / Window" . . and when the page arrives change "Banned" to "People who like this", then find the person there on the list and click "Make Admin".
ALSO if there are any other BLANK boxes below, then click the "x" next to them and remove them, then do the "Save" and add your password, which is the Admin's own personal Facebook login password.
You might have to try it several times to make it work.

If you make that new Admin a "Manager" they will now have as much control of your PAGE as yourself. (If you are asked for a password use your own personal Facebook login password).

If you want to relinquish your Admin status, just click "Remove Admin" against your name, and if you wish to leave the PAGE completely, just view the PAGE and click "Unlike" . . . ALL IS NOW DONE.

Comment: This answer appears to have been copied-and-pasted from this 2013 Facebook User Help Community post: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151531790073592 It should be edited to include proper attribution.

Comment: The link from the previous comment is no longe available. Added post notice requiring citation but it might be more important to update an properly give attribution to the current reputable sources.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to your page settings
2. Click on *page role*
3. Search the name you want to transfer the page to
4. Make them admin.
5. Finally, click *Save settings*.